# Can I attack a specific player?

Tags: clash-of-clans

I was in a clan and someone kicked me from it.

I think I'm stronger than him. Is there any way I can attack him? The only method I see to attack is random players. Can I attack a specific player?

Comment: That sounds rather petty anyway. Get over it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You cannot attack specific players, you can only attack

- Who you find random.
- Someone who attacked you and you tap "revenge" (not available if that player attacked you out of revenge)
- Enemies in a clan war.

Comment: oh.. so I cant revenge against the guy that kick me from the clan?

Comment: No, only if he would attack you by random. Or if you would find him by random.(which are both extremely unlikely)

Answer (score 2):

As of the recent update, you can now practice attack members from your own clan's bases. These attacks (friendly challenges) can be done whenever you wish, and as often as you like. You may use any of your available base layouts to challenge people, so you can test different layouts and see which works best, or test different attack strategies out to get better at them without wasting any troops. These challenges will not grant and loot/trophies, nor will the troops used be destroyed, so you can reuse the troops for as many challenges as you wish.

Answer (score 0):

You can attack but only if  you had joined his clan and he has sent friendly challenge you have to click in attack